# Handling CustomField Insert - Which option is efficient and easier to maintain

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have the following Table structure:

**User Table**

```
UserId  CompanyId   FullName    Email
1       1           Alex        alex@alex.com
2       1           Sam         sam@sam.com
3       2           Rohit       rohit@rohit.com
```

**CustomField Table**

```
CustomFieldId   CompanyId   Name             Type
1               1           DOB              Datetime
2               1           CompanySize      Number
3               2           LandingPage      Text
```

**CustomFieldValue Table**

```
UserId  CustomFieldId   DatetimeValue   NumberValue TextValue
1       2               01-01-2020      
1       2                               10  
1       3                                           Home
2       1           
2       2                               20  
2       3                                           Product
```

Please consider the following facts:

1. There are millions of users in a particular CompanyId
2. When displaying a particular user in the UI we need to show all the Custom Fields that an end customer can fill up.

**How to handle CustomFieldValues table in this case? We are considering the following options**

1. When a new CustomField row is created for a particular CompanyId have a After Insert Trigger to create all corresponding rows in CustomFieldValue table for all users.

   - This I think would have an initial cost of creating so many rows for each Custom Field in the CustomFieldValue Table. (This may also lock up the table and users of the application would have to wait till all the inserts are done).
   - Same issue for deleting all CustomFieldValue rows when a CustomField row is deleted from a Company
   - But easier for UI and backend developers as they don't need to worry about whether a CustomFieldValue doesn't have an entry for a Custom Field that has been created for a Company
2. Don't create CustomFieldValue rows when a CustomField is added to the Company. Create the CustomFieldValue whenever user fills up the relevant input field in the UI view

   - This would have negligible insert cost and users would not have to wait for insert or delete to complete in CustomFieldValue table for all the users in a particular company.
   - The downside is that developers would have to make sure that relevant CustomFields are displayed in the frontend even though no relevant records yet exist in the CustomFieldValue table.
   - On each Custom Field input update by the end user, the developers would have to first check if a corresponding CustomFieldValue row exits, if so - store the updated value, if not - create the CustomFieldValue row.

Kindly suggest a solution which is efficient and easier to maintain.

Comment: How many companies do you have?

Comment: "Kindly suggest a solution which is efficient and easier to maintain." - what you call "custom fields" is a well-worn pattern called the EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) table - and it's _generally_ not a good idea. Consider using a Wide-Table or even `ALTER TABLE` to add columns instead.

Comment: See here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios - "In other words, EAV gives you enough rope to hang yourself and in this industry, things should be designed to the lowest level of complexity because the guy replacing you on the project will likely be an idiot."

Comment: For Wide-Tables, SQL Server has supported them since 2008 R2, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186986(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN - but make sure you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc645884(v=sql.105) - Wide Tables can have up to 30,000 columns - which I _hope_ is enough for most Enterprise-y FactoryBeanFactoryAbstractFactory-type projects...

Comment: Note - DOB is **DATE** of birth, which is not a datetime value.

Comment: @SMor Not necessarily - hospital records would definitely by using `datetimeoffset(7)` for that ;)

Comment: @Gordon we currently have like 20,000 companies. Which would increase.

Comment: @Dai extending the table with new columns would be a very bad idea as we have more than 20,000 companies and it would increase further.
Moreover, its not EAV but a Modified EAV with defined datatype columns.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh You probably shouldn't be using a relational database then - consider something like Cassandra or a Document-Store. Relational databases are over-used and shoehorned into many inappropriate use-cases where other database paradigms are more appropriate (e.g. abusing a table as a queue-store instead of using RabbitMQ, or to store a graph when Neo4J should be used, and so on...). An EAV table in a small project (thousands of rows) is one thing - but as you said we're talking _thousands of millions of rows_ - so **using a traditional RDBMS is a bad idea**.

Comment: What do you do when Amalgamated Widgets LLC adds an `xml` column while Eco Incineration Inc needs a non-nullable `decimal(10,4)` column? The `Failure Code` column for NarfTech needs to be validated against the usual list: `'ERROR_SUCCESS'`, `'FATAL_SUCCESS'` and `'FILE_NOT_FOUND'`. Not a problem? After a few more companies add `NChar(4000)` columns you might begin to approach the limit of [8060 bytes/row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Please do not delete [your closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68053522/handling-customfield-insert-which-option-is-efficient-and-easier-to-maintain) then open an exact duplicate. Instead improve your question to meet the site requirements and it will be reopened.